# Angular splash screen only for PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am new to angular PWA.
I have a requirement, which is  associated with PWA application.
I need to show splash screen when opening the PWA application for a particular time.
It's not necessary to show the splash screen when the application  opening through a browser.
how to achieve this ?.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below articles about splash screen for PWA.

https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210

https://web.dev/add-manifest/#splash-screen